# Comparing percentages

Tags: classification, statistical-significance, chi-squared-test

Question:
I am trying to compare the percentages I have accumulated from a research study. Say that I have collected data on a certain group of patients, all having the same diagnosis. Then I divy them up into male and female. Young, Middle Age, Older. And anatomic locations (say face, back, chest, abdomen and extremities). I assume I need the student T test to see if there is a significance of female > male (and make my mean 50). But how can I compare the multiple anatomic locations or 3 different ages? I am having difficulty setting up a chi square for this.
Thanks!

Comment: It seems to be that you are unsure how to analyze the data.  Your objective should determine what method to use.

Comment: It sounds like you are comparing the incidence of something depending on male/ female, where on the body, age range. You've used 50% for the gender split presumably because that's an approximation of the incidence of genders in life, but check that's valid for your data. For the body location, you might want to consider the proportion of body area occupied by the body part; for age, the proportion of your data set occupied by subjects within each age bracket. Re-writing your question to be explicit about your dependent variable may get more specific answers.